# Backbone and Jquery Datepicker - hover event firing on load of datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, datepicker

In a backbone app I am developing I have a view that renders a jquery datepicker object. I have a hover event attached to the datepicker so that hovering on a date will fire another function I have.

When I render the view, the hover event fires straight away for every day in the datepicker. This does not happen if I change to a click event, so I suspect that the hover event is somehow propagating through on the initial load and firing on each date.

After the initial load everything functions as expected.

Changing to 'mouseenter' or 'mouseover' has no effect.

Any ideas how to mitigate this unwanted event firing?

Comment: You need to include a minimal demo of the view in question and how it is used. A quick demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com would also be helpful.

Comment: I've solved the issue with a workaround by binding the hover event to the datepicker once the calendar has been rendered, instead of using the view's event block. I was waiting until I could answer my own question! But thanks for taking time to read.